# Reducing gap on top of screen due to search box

Tags: html, search-box

I recently add a search box at the top of my site:

www.glucosemeters4u.com

The box has caused a big space from the top of the screen to where my menu bar starts. The space is about 2 inches. I want to shrink this space to about half. How can i do this? Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change 185 height on your td to a lower number:

[image: Image height]

Answer (score 0):

1- Change the TD height from 185 to maybe 50 (in the header row)

2- Change table height from 4072 to 4000

3- Use divs, not tables

4- Use CSS, not inline styles